# Inject configuration from Terraform into Kubernetes without hardcoding

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, configuration-management, environment-variables

I have a pretty simple setup:

- An AWS DocumentDB managed using Terraform
- A container running on EKS, managed in a Flux (GitOps) repository

The container needs to access the DocumentDB, so somehow I need to pass connection string, credentials and CA cert to the container.

My goal is to do so without hardcoding any "magic strings". For example, I could create a K8s secret `docdb-creds` with Terraform and then consume that in my container. But then I would need to know the secret name in the Flux repository. And if it changes, the container would fail at startup and not already in the "plan" phase.

I'm tempted to manage all Kubernetes resources in Terraform - including the deployment manifest - and simply set an environment variable using Terraform's variable system. But I have read and heard that managing Kubernetes resources with Terraform might not be a good idea, because Kubernetes already has a sophisticated state management system. I would be putting the Terraform state management over it just for the convenience of referencing variable values.

There is also the idea of creating the resource manifests using Terraform's output templating, but then I would need to setup some pipeline to commit these files into the Flux repository.

Are there any other ideas out there how to achieve this? Or are there opinions what is the "least evil" of the ideas presented?